# Android SQLiteException: near "(": syntax error (code 1):

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I've spend some time in try to fix this, but I don't know where is the problem in my sql create entries..

The error:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "(": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE CommerceName ( _id TEXT  PRIMARY KEY,id INTEGER,name TEXT,category TEXT,imageref TEXT )
```

Thanks in advance

CODE:

```
 public static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
            "CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE " + CommerceSearchReaderDbHelper.CommerceNameSearchEntry.TABLE_NAME + " ( " +
                    CommerceSearchReaderDbHelper.CommerceNameSearchEntry._ID            + TEXT_TYPE +"  PRIMARY KEY," +
                    CommerceSearchReaderDbHelper.CommerceNameSearchEntry.COLUMN_ID      + INTEGER_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                    CommerceSearchReaderDbHelper.CommerceNameSearchEntry.COLUMN_NAME    + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP  +
                    CommerceSearchReaderDbHelper.CommerceNameSearchEntry.COLUMN_CATEGORY+ TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP  +
                    CommerceSearchReaderDbHelper.CommerceNameSearchEntry.COLUMN_IMAGEREF + TEXT_TYPE +
                    " )";

    public static final String SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES =
            "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + CommerceSearchReaderDbHelper.CommerceNameSearchEntry.TABLE_NAME;

    public static abstract class CommerceNameSearchEntry implements BaseColumns {
        public static final String TABLE_NAME       = "CommerceName";
        public static final String COLUMN_ID        = SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_EXTRA_DATA;
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME      = SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1;
        public static final String COLUMN_CATEGORY  = SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_2;
        public static final String COLUMN_IMAGEREF  = SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_ICON_1;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really intend to create a virtual table, then you are missing "USING module_name". See [here](https://sqlite.org/lang_createvtab.html).

If you instead do not intend to create a virtual table (which is likely since you are using Android), then you should remove "VIRTUAL" from the `CREATE` statement. The syntax is [here](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html).

Comment: what do you mean with: missing "USING module_name

Comment: Virtual tables require a backing implementation. Since you have specified the Android tag, I would actually assume you do not intend to create a virtual table (since that is relatively complicated). More likely you intend to create a regular table. I will update the answer.

Comment: Also, if TEXT_TYPE and INTEGER_TYPE are not defined to include space(s) at the beginning, you may indeed have the problem hinted by the other answer once you sort out the CREATE syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the spaces between your CommerceSearchReaderDbHelper.CommerceNameSearchEntry._ID and TEXT_TYPE, etc. Use this instead:

```
public static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
            "CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE " + 
             CommerceSearchReaderDbHelper.CommerceNameSearchEntry.TABLE_NAME + " ( " + CommerceSearchReaderDbHelper.CommerceNameSearchEntry._ID          
             + " " + TEXT_TYPE +"  PRIMARY KEY," +
                    CommerceSearchReaderDbHelper.CommerceNameSearchEntry.COLUMN_ID + " " + INTEGER_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                    CommerceSearchReaderDbHelper.CommerceNameSearchEntry.COLUMN_NAME + " " + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP  +
                    CommerceSearchReaderDbHelper.CommerceNameSearchEntry.COLUMN_CATEGORY + " " + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP  +
                    CommerceSearchReaderDbHelper.CommerceNameSearchEntry.COLUMN_IMAGEREF + " " + TEXT_TYPE +
             " );";
```